# RSpec Matchers When Working With ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

So here's the method I want to test:

```
def self.by_letter(letter)
  where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{letter}%").order(:lastname)
end
```

Quick question here, what exactly does the percent sign after #{letter} do? Something to do with formatting?

Here's part of the spec that tests that method:

```
    context 'method "by_letter"' do
    it 'returns and ordered list by letter' do
      theon = Contact.create!(
        firstname: "Theon", 
        lastname: "Greyjoy", 
        email: "tgreyjoy@ironprice.com"
        )
      rob = Contact.create!(
       firstname: "Rob", 
       lastname: "Stark", 
       email: "rstark@winterfell.com" 
       )
      tyrion = Contact.create!(
       firstname: "Tyrion", 
       lastname: "Lannister", 
       email: "tlannister@kingslanding.com" 
       )
      result = Contact.by_letter("S")
      expect(result).to include("Snow")
    end
  end
```

And here's the logs I get for an output after running said test (oh, bare in mind, earlier in the spec I created a "Jon Snow", and he should pop up before "Stark" alphabetically):

```
    Failures:

  1) Contact method "by_letter" returns and ordered list by letter
     Failure/Error: expect(result).to include("Snow")
       expected #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Contact id: 1, firstname: "Jon", lastname: "Snow", email: "lordcommander@nightswatch.com", created_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:55", updated_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:55">, #<Contact id: 3, firstname: "Rob", lastname: "Stark", email: "rstark@winterfell.com", created_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:56", updated_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:56">]> to include "Snow"
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
       -["Snow"]
       +[#<Contact id: 1, firstname: "Jon", lastname: "Snow", email: "lordcommander@nightswatch.com", created_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:55", updated_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:55">,
       + #<Contact id: 3, firstname: "Rob", lastname: "Stark", email: "rstark@winterfell.com", created_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:56", updated_at: "2014-11-14 17:17:56">]
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't my test pass because I return a collection that includes a string I specified? Is there some complication because it's not a regular array but some sort of proxy array? What do I need to do to get my test to pass?

Comment: http://pivotallabs.com/testing-active-record-scopes/ This is doing something very similar, AR::Relation does not know how to find "Snow" #include?, which causes your error. You could match on the objects though.

Answer (score 5):

Your `result` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. So you should do as below :-

```
expect(result).to include(rob)
```

`rob` has the last name as `"Stark"`, thus `Contact.by_letter("S")` will include `rob` in the *filtered* list.

Answer (score 3):

Try `expect(result.first).to include("Snow")`

You can also say (preferably):

`expect(result.first.lastname).to eq("Snow")`

Comment: I like this solution the best, as it directly answered my question and gave me a different way approach the problem.

Comment: @ilrein But your testing _approach_ is completely wrong. Your method 's purpose as I am seeing if it _filters_ correct objects or not.. And you should test accordingly..

Comment: Yeah, you can tell I'm just getting my feet wet with testing. I tried something like expect(Contact.by_letter("Z")).to_not include tyrion, rob, theon which worked as expected. Thanks!